# bootstrap grid with bootstrap carousel messed up, bootstrap carousel bothers the grid system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is what I'm trying to do. 
I want bootstrap carousel to have col-sm-8. and I want to put a table that shows top stories in col-sm-4. 
And then below those two. I want to have three `col-sm-4` that contains the list of categories.
Problem I'm having is carousel invades col-sm-4. It should end its space in col-sm-8 but it goes there any way. Also I'm not sure how to have col-sm-8 and col-sm-4 in the top section. and below col-sm-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-4. What I tried was put div around top section. and one div for below section. But this doesn't work. As I'm a noob, I would appreciate any kind of advice or help. Thank you.

```
<div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<div class='carousel slide' id="myCarousel" style="width:1400px; margin:0 auto">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
<li class="active" data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
<li class="active" data-slide-to="2" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    </ol>


    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active" id="slide1">
                                <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/SQ691ZO.jpg" />

            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>hello</h4>
                <p>hi you</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="item" id="slide2">
                            <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/SQ691ZO.jpg" />

            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>hello</h4>
                <p>hi you</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="item" id="slide3">
                            <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/SQ691ZO.jpg" />

            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>hello</h4>
                <p>hi you</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

<a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel"><span class="icon-prev"></span></a>
<a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel"><span class="icon-next"></span></a>


</div>
</div>
<div class=col-sm-4>
    hello you
</div>
</div>

<div>
<div class=col-sm-4>
    category one
</div>
<div class=col-sm-4>
    category two
</div>
<div class=col-sm-4>
    category three
</div>
```

Comment: the first div should have either the container or container-fluid class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The bootstrap grid system**

The bootstrap grid has a certain setup you should use. First you create a `container`, this can be either fixed with `.container` or fluid (from the left to the right side) `.container-fluid`.

Inside the container you can create `.row`s, to nest columns in it.

A basic setup for your needs could be:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">8 Columns</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">4 Columns</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">3 Columns</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">3 Columns</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">3 Columns </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/marianrick/cayt1hkp/2/)

You can read about it on [bootstrap grid introduction](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro).

---

**Adopt grid system**

If you adapt this to your code it could look like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class='carousel slide' id="myCarousel">
         <!--slider content -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class=col-sm-4>
      hello you
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--.row-->

  <div class="row">
    <div class=col-sm-4>
      category one
    </div>
    <div class=col-sm-4>
      category two
    </div>
    <div class=col-sm-4>
      category three
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--.container-->
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/marianrick/cayt1hkp/3/)

---

**Slider width**

To fix the slider, which gets too big, you have to remove `style="width:1400px; margin:0 auto"` from its div. Afterwards it should adjust its size automatically.